# How to convert ts to mp4

Tags: video, software-recommendation, streaming, mp4, file-formats

I have a lot of videos needed to convert from ts to mp4, how can I convert it without losing quality? I mean a lot like 30+ each week.
I did a search already but none can do it fast enough, doing it manually will takes me half an hour.
Is there any software do it for free?
Please teach me step by step I am not computer geek.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i video.ts -codec copy video.mp4`

Comment: I have a lot of files. I know this method, i want quicker tool @SlimSCSI

Comment: That is the fastest way. Automatically looping over a list of files in a bash/cmd script is super easy.

Comment: There are a million examples of how do write a shell script on the internet.

Comment: Is bash a program name? When I sesrch it there a few application named Bash

Comment: Search for “bash shell”. It the Mac/Linux equivalent of windows cmd/powershell

Comment: if you are looking for lighweight tool use [Medlexo](https://www.medlexo.ml). Google the official site

Comment: It would be really helpful to write a step by step answer of how to do this @SlimSCSI

Comment: That really depend what do you want to achieve, if you want fast and lossless I think Medlexo is suitable for this job. It's free

Answer (score 0):

There are two FFmpeg frontends that I have used quite a bit for batch video conversion:

- [WinFF](https://www.biggmatt.com/p/winff.html)
- [XMedia Recode](https://www.xmedia-recode.de/en/)

They are both for Windows, but I know there are more free FFmpeg frontends out there for other platforms. [QWinFF](https://qwinff.github.io/) is for Windows & Linux, but I think development has ceased.

- https://alternativeto.net/tag/ffmpeg/
- https://alternativeto.net/tag/ffmpeg-gui/

Answer (score 0):

At best, you can use the software **Handbrake**
It greatly reduces the video volume and has little effect on the quality. In this software, make changes to the resolution section and other items. I'm sure if you test a few times you will notice its very good performance and this software is free.